# What is the third parameter passed to listener?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I currently started playing with the `d3` framework. I observed that for `v3` there is a third parameter passed to the event listener. It seems to be always `0` but I cannot find any information on what it is suppose to represent?

From the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#on):

> The specified listener is invoked in the same manner as other operator functions, being passed the current datum d and index i, with the this context as the current DOM element.

What is the meaning of this third parameter?

---

In this example you will see that once you click any of the rectangles 3 parameters are passed to `f`:

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")

function f(d, idx, whoami) {
    console.log('I am the data:\t' + d);
    console.log('I am the index:\t' + idx);
    console.log('But who am i?\t' + whoami);
    console.log('Length:' + arguments.length);
    console.log(arguments);
}

var data = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

svg.selectAll('rect')
  .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", function(el, i) {return i * 40;})
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 40)
    .on("click", f);
```

```css
rect {
  fill: #333;
  opacity: 0.3;
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: [`dispatch`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_dispatch) says something about _“current group (`nodes`)”_.

Comment: It's the nodes in the selection, convention is not as standard for what to call the third parameter, but if it is `nodes`, then in the listener: `this == nodes[i]`.

Comment: @AndrewReid But it’s `0`. It can’t be `0[i]`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon hmm, I hadn't thought d3v4/5 and v3 were different in that regard, will require a closer look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is actually an undocumented feature. Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/selection/on.js) of `selection.on()` back in v3.5.17 you will notice that `selection.each()` is [used internally](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/selection/on.js#L30) to bind the listener to each node of the current selection.

```
return this.each(d3_selection_on(type, listener, capture));
```

From there on the internal function [`d3_selection_on`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/selection/on.js#L33) will evaluate to [`onAdd`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/selection/on.js#L50) for the addition of listeners and the reference to the `onAdd` function will be passed as the callback to `.each()`. Therefore, `.each()` will actually execute `onAdd` for every node in the current selection. `onAdd`, on the other hand, will close over the arguments passed to it by the `.each()` call whereby [storing](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/selection/on.js#L91) them in the listener's context:

```
function d3_selection_on(type, listener, capture) {

  /* ... */

  function onAdd() {
    var l = wrap(listener, d3_array(arguments));  // wrap points to d3_selection_onListener
    /* ... */
  }

  /* ... */

function d3_selection_onListener(listener, argumentz) {
  return function(e) {
    /* ... */
    argumentz[0] = this.__data__;                 // Set the latest datum as the first argument
    try {
      listener.apply(this, argumentz);            // Pass arguments from closure to the listener
    } finally {
      d3.event = o;
    }
  };
}
```

Looking at the implementation of [`selection.each()`](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/selection/each.js) one notices that not just two arguments—as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Selections.md#each)—are passed to the callback but rather [three arguments](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/9cc9a875e636a1dcf36cc1e07bdf77e1ad6e2c74/src/selection/each.js#L12):

```
if (node = group[i]) callback(node, i, j);
```

The third argument `j` being the group's index. Since your code does not make use of grouping that argument always evaluates to `0`.

Modifying your demo one can easily demonstrate how setting up a grouped selection affects the value of that third argument. The following snippet duplicates your three rects putting each set of rects into one `<g>` while establishing a grouping using a sub-selection with its own data binding.

```js
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")

function f(d, idx, whoami) {
    console.log('I am the data:\t' + d);
    console.log('I am the index:\t' + idx);
    console.log('But who am i?\t' + whoami);
    console.log('Length:' + arguments.length);
    console.log(arguments);
}

var data = [['A', 'B', 'C'], ['a', 'b', 'c']];

svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('g')
  .selectAll('rect')
  .data(d => d)
  .enter().append('rect')
    .attr("x", function(el, i, j) {return j * 110;})
    .attr("y", function(el, i) {return i * 40;})
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 40)
    .on("click", f, true);
```

```css
rect {
  fill: #333;
  opacity: 0.3;
  stroke: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.js"></script>
```

Again, this is totally undocumented as it is mentioned neither in the documentation on `.each()` nor in the one on `.on()`.

Comment: Sometimes I think D3 docs are too superficial... But then I see some libraries with their so-called docs so deficient that I change my mind, D3 docs are quite good.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Exactly. I am always surprised how good the D3 documentation actually is. At least, if compared to others. Honestly, I think it is one of the best documentations of free software I have ever come across. It's not perfect, still most questions can be answered by reading the docs. U4D

Comment: Agree with both of you, I'm always a bit annoyed when I see questions here saying the docs are horrible when they tend to answer that same question. Especially when compared with most other libraries that seem way worse. The docs are even more impressive if you were to combine each module's docs into one document, it's a huge effort. @altocumulus, nice work tracking down the answer.

Comment: @AndrewReid There is an interesting development that Fil pointed out to me in a [comment](https://github.com/d3/d3/issues/3452#issuecomment-727053326) on an issue I opened on the GitHub repo: some work is in progress to make the API.md files machine readable! See demo applications at https://observablehq.com/d/3892df5ed9d82978 and https://observablehq.com/d/352e015b493a0a84. That is so awesome!

Comment: So it is the group ID. Then it actually _is_ documented indirectly in [`dispatch`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_dispatch).

Comment: @SebastianSimon No, that's a totally different thing. Firstly, the documentation you linked to is the one for the latest version 6. For v3 things were a bit different: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Internals.md#d3_dispatch. Secondly, the docs are talking about the *nodes*, i.e. the group's contents, whereas the third parameter gets the group's index, i.e. the index of the group itself. Thirdly, `d3.dispatch` is not involved in the entire call stack for this piece of code.

Comment: Funnily enough, some @GerardoFurtado guy (not sure if I have heard of him before, seems to be quite into D3, though) posted an interesting insight into this issue some 4 and a half years ago: [*"d3.js v4: How to access parent group's datum index?"*](/q/38233003). This sheds some more light on case.